# Eager load associations when querying against association data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a model "User" which has a one-to-many relationship with another model "Membership".  Membership has a field named "group" which has the name of a group.  I want to query for all the User records that are in a particular "group" and eager load all "memberships" for each User returned.

Before I go further, I know that normally you would implement a "Group" model and make Membership a join table between User and Group and just query the specific Group for all its users.  This example is a little contrived, but it represents the real case I'm working on.

Anyway, I tried the following query:

```
User.includes(:memberships).where(memberships: { group: groupname })
```

However, while this returns the correct users, it only eager loads the memberships that matches the query.  To put it another way, if a user "Bob" is in the "red" and "blue" groups and I query for all "blue" group users, the user "Bob" is returned among the results but only his "blue" group membership is loaded.

Is there a way to do this with a single DB query AND eager load all memberships of each returned user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example a single DB query is performed because there is a query condition on the association. Normally, `includes` would perform two DB queries, one to load the users and the other to load the associated memberships.

I paid attention to that because there is a solution that works performing two DB queries and it is fine (default ActiveRecord eager loading behavior)

```
User.preload(:memberships).joins(:memberships).where(memberships: {group: groupname})
```

**Note:** in the example the `preload` method is used instead of `includes`. That is for query conditions on the associated table to be applied only in the first query and to not affect the second query that preloads `memberships`. By default when there are no extra query conditions on associated table `include` works like `preload`.

The first query will fetch all the users having memberships of required group.

The second query will fetch all associated memberships without any extra condition.

Comment: This looks good.  Yes, I did say "single DB query", but what I really meant was "fixed set of queries regardless of the number of users", so this works nicely.  Just to make sure I understand what's happening here, the "joins" does an inner join so the "where" clause can do matching on users based on group name, but does not actually load any membership data.  The "preload" call actually loads the membership data into memory but, because it's doing it into a separate query, it is unaffected by the "where" clause.  Does that sound about right?

Comment: That's right. I would also like to clarify one thing: The "preload" call is unaffected by the "where" clause not only because it is a separate query, but also because Rails doesn't add the "where" clause to the query. If you used `include` instead of `preload`, you would have the same "where" clause in both queries. In fact, I can't say that it is expected behaviour, it is just how it works.

Comment: Thanks.  I always wondered why anyone would ever use preload over includes.  Now I know.